# PyTorch: Training classes and evaluation classes are different by indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am training a `resnet-152` model with classes names are `0, 1, 2, 3 ..... 15`. When I debug `classes`. The indexes of all classes are shuffle and it does not affect on training but affecting evaluation and testing results. Any way to sort classes with numbers before training? How I arrange the class names during testing?

**[Code] **train.py****

```
class_names = dataset['train'].classes
print("Classes:", class_names)
Output of Classes: ['0', '1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

print("Classes:", dataloaders['train'].dataset.class_to_idx)
Classes Index: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '10': 2, '11': 3, '12': 4, '13': 5, '14': 6, '2': 7, '3': 8, '4': 9, '5': 10, '6': 11, '7': 12, '8': 13, '9': 14}
```

**[Code] test.py**
I have no idea whether class labels are arrange correctly or not. The network accuracy is 50% while testing it shows 0 because target labels are not arrange properly.

```
# Class labels for prediction
class_names = ['Abstract_Expressionism', 'Art_Nouveau_Modern',  'Post_Impressionism', 'Rococo', 'Romanticism',
               'Symbolism', 'Baroque', 'Color_Field_Painting', 'Cubism',
               'Early_Renaissance',
                'Ukiyo_e', 'Expressionism', 'Fauvism', 'Impressionism', 'Pop_Art']
```